# How to propgate matrix definition across multiple stages in Azure Pipelines

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I'm writing a multi-stage job in Azure Pipelines that involves generating a matrix from a script as an output of a stage. I want to use that matrix across multiple stages to generate jobs, but I want to use conditions on jobs from a previous stage using that matrix.

Example azure-pipelines.yml:

```yaml
stages:
- stage: A
  jobs: 
   - job: generateMatrix
- stage: B
  dependsOn: A
  jobs:
    - job: "" # This lets the job name be just the name of the matrix key
      continueOnError: true # steps in these jobs may or may not fail
      strategy:
        matrix: $[ stageDependencies.A.generateMatrix.outputs['matrix'] ]
- stage: C
  dependsOn: # Needs A's matrix and B job results
    - A
    - B
  jobs: 
    - job: "" # The job name here should be the same as in stage B
      continueOnError: true 
      strategy:
        matrix: $[ stageDependencies.A.generateMatrix.outputs['matrix'] ]
      steps:
        - script: echo "Job from Stage B Succeeded"
          condition: eq(stageDependencies.B.variables['Agent.JobName'].result, 'Succeeded')
        - script: echo "Job from Stage B Failed"
          condition: condition: ne(stageDependencies.B.variables['Agent.JobName'].result, 'Succeeded')
```

So I need to be able one of the following:

- Be able to parameterize the json path inside the stage dependencies
- Be able to edit and add a variable to the existing matrix in Stage (B) and somehow output that.

Does anyone have any idea on how to do this? I tried the above but it failed.

Comment: Do you mean you want to modify the matrix value from stage B in stage C?

Comment: I want Stage B to modify the matrix outputted in stage A and then have C read that matrix.

Essentially the matrix outputted at stage A looks like

```json
{
"foo": {"var1": "val1"},
...
}

```

and I want to add another value into that matrix such that 


```json
{
"foo": {"var1": "val1", "var2": "val2"},
...
}

```

Comment: I could also see this being sovled by having a "collect" job as a second Job in stage B that could rewrite the matrix with the updated values, so long as the matrixed job could output vars that would be readable by the "collect" job

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid we can not modify the matrix output from Stage A in Stage B. You need to define a new output in Stage B and then use in Stage C.